# Why std::condition_variable does not work properly? Notify always before wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

```
void VideoRender::execute(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
       udpateData(myPath, myIndex);
}

void VideoRender::updateData(const std::string &i_obj_path, const uint i_subIndex)
{
    std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> container = std::make_shared<FrameManager>(m_nativeCodec);

    std::thread th1(&VideoRender::loadGeometry, this, i_obj_path.c_str(), i_subIndex, container);
    std::thread th2(&VideoRender::loadTextures, this, container);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    m_fifo.enqueue(container);
}
```

Problem here that every time when `updateData` method invoked 2 new threads are created.

So, I decided to change this logic to something that use `std::condition_variable`

What I have done

1) Created `ConditionEvent` class

h.file

```
namespace hello_ar
{
class ConditionEvent
{
public:
    ConditionEvent() = default;

    ~ConditionEvent() = default;

    void wait();

    void notify();

private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
};

}
```

cc file

```
#include "ConditionEvent.h"
#include <android/log.h>

namespace hello_ar
{
void ConditionEvent::wait()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_condition.wait(lock);
}

void ConditionEvent::notify()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_condition.notify_all();
}
}
```

Then I created a `UploadLooper` class

h file

```
namespace hello_ar
{
class UploadLooper
{
public:
    UploadLooper() = default;

    ~UploadLooper();

    void start();

    void enqueueLoadTextureTask(const std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> &container, std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition);

    void enqueueLoadGeometryTask(const std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> &container, char const *filename, const uint subIndex, 
std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition);

    void quit();

private:
    enum class Task
    {
        LoadGeometry, LoadTexture, ERROR
    };

    struct LooperMessage
    {
        std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> m_container;
        std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> m_condition;
        char const *m_filename;
        uint m_subIndex;
        Task m_task;

        //Load Geometry
        LooperMessage(std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> container, //
                      std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition,//
                      char const *filename = "", //
                      const uint subIndex = static_cast<const uint>(-1),//
                      Task task = Task::ERROR //
        ) : m_container(container), m_condition(condition), 
 m_filename(filename), m_subIndex(subIndex), m_task(task)
        {
        }

        //Load Textures
        LooperMessage(std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> container, //
                      std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition,//
                      Task task = Task::ERROR//
        ) : LooperMessage(container, //
                          condition,
                          "", //
                          static_cast<uint>(-1), //
                          task//
        )
        {
        }
    };

    safe_queue<std::shared_ptr<LooperMessage>> m_fifo;
    std::thread m_worker;

    void loop();

    void trampoline(void *p);

    void releaseWorker();
};
}
```

cc file

```
namespace hello_ar
{
UploadLooper::~UploadLooper()
{
    quit();
}

void UploadLooper::releaseWorker()
{
    if (m_worker.joinable())
        m_worker.join();
}

void UploadLooper::trampoline(void *p)
{
    ((UploadLooper *) p)->loop();
}

void UploadLooper::loop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (m_fifo.empty())
            continue;

        std::shared_ptr<LooperMessage> msg = m_fifo.dequeue();

        if (!msg)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (msg->m_task)
        {
            case Task::LoadGeometry:
            {
                msg->m_container->LoadFrameData(msg->m_filename, msg->m_subIndex);
                msg->m_condition->notify();
            }
                break;

            case Task::LoadTexture:
            {
                msg->m_container->LoadImage();
                msg->m_condition->notify();
            }
                break;
            case Task::ERROR:
                break;
        }

        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

void UploadLooper::enqueueLoadTextureTask(const std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> &container, std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition)
{
    std::shared_ptr<LooperMessage> msg = std::make_shared<LooperMessage>(container, condition, Task::LoadTexture);
    m_fifo.enqueue(msg);
}

void UploadLooper::enqueueLoadGeometryTask(const std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> &container, //
                                           char const *filename, const uint subIndex, //
                                           std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> condition)
{
    std::shared_ptr<LooperMessage> msg = std::make_shared<LooperMessage>(container, condition, filename, subIndex, Task::LoadGeometry);
    m_fifo.enqueue(msg);
}

void UploadLooper::quit()
{
    m_fifo.enqueue(nullptr);
    releaseWorker();
}

void UploadLooper::start()
{
    if (!m_worker.joinable())
    {
        std::thread t(&UploadLooper::trampoline, this, this);
        m_worker = std::move(t);
    }
}
}
```

Eventually my begging implementation looks like this

```
void VideoRender::execute(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
       udpateData(myPath, myIndex);
}

void VideoRender::updateData(const std::string &i_obj_path, const uint i_subIndex)
{
    std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> container = std::make_shared<FrameManager>(m_nativeCodec);

    std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> texCond = std::make_shared<ConditionEvent>();
    std::shared_ptr<ConditionEvent> geoCond = std::make_shared<ConditionEvent>();

    m_texLopper.enqueueLoadTextureTask(container, texCond);
    m_geometryLopper.enqueueLoadGeometryTask(container, i_obj_path.c_str(), i_subIndex, geoCond);

    texCond->wait();
    geoCond->wait();

    m_fifo.enqueue(container);
}
```

But after debugging I found out that after first time I invoke `updateData` method I came to `m_texLopper` call `notify`, then I came to `m_geometryLooper` call `notify` and just after this I came to `texCond->wait()` ... Despite of loopers runs in separate threads...

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Problem is - it is impossible that `notify` is invoked before `wait`. Because of according to the implementation I push task to looper (task execution time is 30 milliseconds) and next line is `wait`. So, I push the task to separate thread -> next line `wait` -> after 30 milliseconds `notify`... But it works like push task -> after 30 milliseconds notify -> `wait`... How is it possible?

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. This is way too much code, to keep track off. 2) "_Despite of loopers runs in separate threads_" Yes? There's nothing stopping `notify` being called before execution reaches `wait`. Classic race condition.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but problem is - it is impossible that `notify` invoke` before `wait`. Because of according to the implementation I push task to looper (task execution time is 30 milliseconds) and next line is `wait`. So, I push the task to separate thread -> next line `wait` -> after 30 milliseconds `notify`... But it works like push task -> after 30 milliseconds notify -> wait... How is it possible?

Comment: The scheduler can pause any of your threads at any time to allow other threads to execute. How to solve this: Don't use condition variable without a condition: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

Comment: I didn't read all your code carefully - as there's a lot of it - but first glance looks like you're creating a new condition variable for each job rather than using just the 1

Comment: Also, you have busy wait if `m_fifo.empty()` returns true.

Comment: If you want to wait each "item" in `updateData`, then why not use `std::async` instead (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). I think it would make your code simpler.

Comment: If you are serious about multithreading, you should buy Anthony Williams book: **C++ Concurrency in Action**. There are a few things that seems suspicious in your code and in you reasoning about threads.

Comment: @Phil1970 1) `m_fifo.empty()` yes, it is busy wait, but I don't see another way to make looper... 2) `std::async` I am not sure that it is applicable here... Because I the main reason why I made `looper` is I don't want to create 2 new threads every time when `updateData()` execute... But `std::async` actually create new thread under the hood...

Comment: `std::async` could use a thread pool (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) thus it might not be that much overhead.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `notify_all` instead of `notify_one`. I think that one should prefer calling `notify_one` if he intend to wake up one thread at most. `notify_all` would be use for cases like a **cancel all** notification.

Answer (score 2):

It is not impossible for `notify()` to be invoked before `wait()`. When you are using multiple threads, their execution can start and stop at any time. Your task executes very quickly, so it is reasonable that the first thread might not continue execution before the second thread has finished.

You are expecting this:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
enqueue
wait                 dequeue
                     LoadFrameData()
                     notify
```

But this is also possible:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
enqueue
                     dequeue
                     LoadFrameData()
                     notify
wait
```

You should add a condition to check whenever your condition variable is notified. The whole code can be simplified like this:

```
class ConditionEvent {
public:
    void ConditionEvent::wait() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_condition.wait(lock, [&]() {return notified;});
    }

    void ConditionEvent::set() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        notified = true;
        m_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void reset() {
        notified = false;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    bool notified = false;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
};


void VideoRender::execute() {
    std::shared_ptr<FrameManager> container;
    ConditionEvent geometry, textures;

    // If this thread obtains the lock, initialize the container
    auto init = [&]() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(containerMutex);
        if (!container) {
            container = std::make_shared<FrameManager>(m_nativeCodec);
        }
    };

    // If this thread obtains the lock, enqueue the container
    auto enqueue = [&]() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(containerMutex);
        if (container) {
            m_fifo.enqueue(container);
            container.reset();
            geometry.reset();
            textures.reset();           
        }
    };

    std::thread t1([]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            init();     
            loadGeometry();
            geometry.set();
            textures.wait();
            enqueue();            
        }
    });
    std::thread t2([]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            init();
            loadTextures();
            textures.set();
            geometry.wait();
            enqueue();
        }
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: no, it is not applicable... I can't load 1000 containers in memory. I will get OOM... So, because of this I am using `queue`, there another thread from other side that consume this containers. Did you get my idea? From one side I am filling a `queue` from other side consuming...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko How about the first example (without any thread)? In such case you would only have 1 container in memory at a time. Do you need to run `loadGeometry` and `loadTextures` in parallel?

Comment: Yes, because I need to get container max every 30 milliseconds... So, in order to save time I need to execute this tasks in parallel

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I have updated the code, it should now only use one container at a time.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of `ConditionEvent::reset` function. And it is suspicious that it modify a variable shared among thread without a lock or being an atomic variable. Maybe to reused objects once you got the result?

Comment: @Phil1970 `reset()` clears the event so that it can be reused during the next loop round. In this case, `reset()` is only called in `enqueue` and thus protected by `containerMutex`. But you are correct it would be better as atomic.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add variable to `ConditionEvent`, i.e.

```
bool notified = false;
```

Then use this variable:

```
void ConditionEvent::wait()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_condition.wait(lock, [this]() {return notified;});
}

void ConditionEvent::notify()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    notified = true;
    m_condition.notify_all();
}
```

Edit: Fixed lambda.

Comment: Do not use `volatile` for thread safety, it does not help. `std::atomic_bool` can help instead.

Comment: It is not for thread safety, since it is already protected by mutex.

Comment: but problem here that I have two instances of `ConditionEvent` it is means that I can't use global `notified = false`. I need to have this value for each `ConditionEvent` instance... But if value `notified` class member it won't give me put it as param in `wait()`. So, we came to solution that I have to exclude it from params and put this value as condition for while. And yes it will work...

Comment: Don't get why " if value `notified` class member it won't give me put it as param in `wait()`"? Usually it works exactly like that.

Comment: @sklott this is what I get `error: 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context  m_condition.wait(lock, []() { return notified; });`, do not you?

Comment: Oops. Forgot to capture :) It should be either `[this]` or `[&]` instead of just `[]`.

Comment: Ok, but there is another issue, as I understand you can't use `bool` you should use `atomic_bool` , but atomic bool does not have copy constructor...... So, again you need to exclude second param and put it as a `while(!notified)` condition before `wait()`, right?

Comment: Why you can't use bool??? Its perfectly ok to use any non-atomic type, including bool, when you access it while holding mutex, which you are doing.